# How to give javascript path in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I working on my local network. I have a server.js file and index.html file in the same directory named app. This app folder is in c directory on windows machine. Originally my index.html file had following two paths.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I found that when I connect my machine on internet then it works fine but when machine is on LAN then the socket things does not work. I have socket.io installed in  app\node_modules\socket.io\client-dist Please suggest how should I give path.

Comment: This expects a path like `https://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js` to exist for a site `https://example.com/`

Comment: **Danger**: jQueyr 1.7.2 is very old, unsupported and has [known security problems](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/version_id-235565/Jquery-Jquery-1.7.2.html) upgrade to the latest version of jQuery or [stop using it](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to load the HTML document from your hard disk instead of running the server with Node.js and then loading the HTML document from your server using HTTP. Your network communication code needs to be dealing with a network service, not a file system.

Comment: Are you using express.js on back end?

Comment: @ptts yes, I am using express.js

Comment: @Quentin I am loading my page as http://localhost:3000